# Form submit button with ajax, replace form with another one (error 500)

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I am trying to turn my Form into multi-step ajax form.

I have:

```
class ProjektForm extends FormBase {

    public function getFormId() { return 'projekt_form'; }


    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $form['title'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Title*:'),
            '#required' => TRUE
        );
        $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
        $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Add'),
            '#button_type' => 'primary',
        '#ajax' => [
            'wrapper' => 'projekt-form-ajax-id',
            'callback' => 'form_ajax_submit',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade'
        ]
        );
        $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="projekt-form-wrapper">';
        $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
        return $form;

    }

    public function form_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
        return 'OK';
    }
...
```

But when I click on "Add" (submit) button and see the "please wait" Drupal icon for a while **I eventually get 500 error** for my ajax request:
[image]

Should I register somehow `form_ajax_submit`? Note that it's member function of `ProjektForm`. And I use `ProjektForm` inside my custom module which displays it from block.

What I want to do is to send the data from form via AJAX (and here I get error 500), validate it and display next form (via ajax, replacing the previous one without page reload).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your namespaced class to the `callback` property.
For example:

```
'callback' => 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\ProjektForm::form_ajax_submit'
```

or

```
'callback' => [$this, 'form_ajax_submit']
```

You also need to make sure the wrapper and the prefix html id are the same.

Finally, after you do all that, do check your logs for more details on the error that caused the 500 response.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. What is strange, when I changed the callback as you propoused and cleared the cache... my form no longer works on ajax and it just sends itself normal way (with page refresh). How is that even possible?

Comment: And the earlier calls logged "Strict warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method ". Which looks like they prevent me from using member of form for callback?

Comment: projekt-form-ajax-id <> projekt-form-wrapper

Comment: Thank you! I've changed the names to match each other. On Firefox I have non-ajax form now (eh... I will leave it for now), on Chrome I have ajax form with 500 error and no errors in Drupal log after I've changed `form_ajax_submit` to `static`.

Comment: Ur welcome! You should use public, not static.

Comment: I've tried with both public and static and any combination of those. I still have error 500 :/ The ids are adjusted and the Drupal log is clear. I've also tried the second version of callback you propoused. I really don't see where's the error now and why I cannot get status 200 response.

Comment: Do you have access to the apache logs? There should be some more details for the 500 error.

Comment: I didn't have access to Apache log. But try by try I eliminated error - I needed to include some classes and modify form_state object instead of return string in `form_ajax_submit`. Overall, it works now. Thank you very much for support on that topic :)